# USB keyboard works except in terminal window

Tags: command-line, 12.10, usb, keyboard

I just installed 12.10 (clean install and updates). USB keyboard and mouse work fine EXCEPT the keyboard does not work in a terminal window (USB mouse is working in terminal). keyboard is Logitech MK320 and associated mouse. I'm typing in a mozilla window on the keyboard at this very moment and when I switch to the terminal window, nothing can be typed.

Any ideas? I use terminal mode alot.

Answer (score 2):

The OP [fixed](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/218325/2) the problem:

> I didn't realize passwords do not show even an asterisk in terminal
>   mode! I'd just installed 12.10 and was pasting a long `sudo` command
>   and then typing my password (which looked like nothing appearing).